# VBA Macro to find entire URLs in Word File

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hello: I am trying to find entire URLs in a Word file. For the most part, they begin with http, but the ending is not always going to be .html. I've tried using regex expressions (something I'm familiar with), but they don't seem to work in VBA. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample URLs and the code you are using.

Comment: You can find help with using wildcards in Find at the [Word MVP site](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a starting point and modify it to your needs.

```
Sub FixHyperlinks()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim lnk As Word.Hyperlink
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each lnk In doc.Content.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print lnk.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rich: Unfortunately, by the time I get the files, the hyperlink has had the "Remove Hyperlink" action performed on it so the text of the hyperlink is left.

Comment: Some examples of the "http" values I encounter include:https://www.vspn.com/sportscentury/features/0001-6385/2018-02-06-top.html;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR7X2dUSwco; and https://vault.si.com/vault/1985/03/11/the-heir-to-the-bear